# ASP.NET + C#. Creating word document from template

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have a word document which contains only one page filled with text and graphic. The page also contains some placeholders like [Field1],[Field2],..., etc. 
I get data from database and I want to open this document and fill placeholders with some data. For each data row I want to open this document, fill placeholders with row's data and then concatenate all created documents into one document. 
What is the best and simpliest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to use a third party library.

You might want to check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra

The below section specifically discusses replacing values in a Word document.

http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2013/09/28/C-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Programmatically-Using-DocX.aspx#Find-and-Replace-Text-Using-DocX---Merge-Templating--Anyone-

Comment: Thanks! DocX is really helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of some third party i will suggest you openXML

add following namespaces System.Text.RegularExpressions;
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging; and DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

```
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello world!");
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Hi Everyone!");

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
}
```